# Submit Image Inside Input Form Field?

Tags: css, forms, icons, field

I was wondering, how can I use an image to submit a form (click the image to submit)? Also, can that image actually be inside the form field?

Answer (score 1):

`use input type image`
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="javascript:document.formName.submit();"><img src="path/to/iamge.png"></a>
```

Substitute "formName" for the name of your form.

Comment: No, that's not what I meant, I know that !
I meant the image that submitts the form is actually inside the form field.

Comment: uhm.. okay... it works though. You can use any image to submit any form this way. You can place the image/anchor tag inside the form tags.